# Some servers refuse to send SMTP emails with Java: "No authentication mechansims supported by both server and client"

Tags: java, exception, smtp

I have the same SMTP email code deployed on various servers (about 6 machines, currently). We have a test job scheduled to run against these machines, one at a time. In other words, I'm passing the same information to each server: same credentials, same smtp server, same port number, etc. The only differences are the subject and body text. These two fields are unique on a per-execution basis.

We use the javax.mail package for this code.

Now, this code works on four of the machines, but on two of them, I receive the following error message:

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechansims supported by both server and client

Any ideas on how to debug this? I don't understand why the SAME code with the SAME credentials and the SAME authentication stuff would be failing on some machines, but not others.

I'll edit this post with developments as I come across them.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're sure that the same code behaves at different servers, then most probably your smtp server treats these servers differently. Maybe different authentication mechanisms are required for these two?

Comment: Are they running different versions of Java or OS?

Comment: @artbristol, yes they are most definitely running different OS's (this is why we have these machines in the first place), but the java version should be identical (though I haven't checked as of now).

Comment: @utkuerd, you were absolutely correct. I didn't realize that these servers were not in the 'trusted hosts' list. I had our sysadmin check that and subsequently add these machines and now it works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction... I must be tired or something :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The machines in question weren't in the trusted hosts list on the SMTP server.